# how i use in wix toolset V4 FirewallException?

Tags: .net, wix, windows-installer, wix4

How use FirewallException? I added xlmns and it still gives this error:

C:\Users\root\Downloads\glpi\glpi\glpi_.wxs(331) : error WIX0200: The File element contains an unhandled extension element 'FirewallException'. Please ensure that the extension for elements in the 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/firewall' namespace has been provided.

I heard it was something with a dll extension, but I didn't find anything about it, I'm using wix v4, using the command: wix build msi.wxs
the code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:fire="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/firewall">
...
    <Component Id="java2" Guid="811DDBF2-1744-4A9D-96CA-93781A5C435C">
        <File Id="java2" Source="GLPI\java\bin\java.exe" KeyPath="yes">
            <Permission User="Everyone" GenericAll="yes"/>
            <fire:FirewallException id="fwxJavaFirewall" DisplayName="java" Scope="any" protocol="tcp" Port="80" Program="[INSTALLFOLDER]java\bin\java.exe" />
        </File>
    </Component>
...
</Wix>
```

I tried to use "wix build msi.wxs -ext WixFirewallException", no results:

```
C:\Users\root\Downloads\glpi\glpi>wix build  glpi_.wxs -ext WixFirewallException
wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixFirewallException' could not be found. Checked paths: WixFirewallException

C:\Users\root\Downloads\glpi\glpi>wix build  glpi_.wxs -ext WixFirewall
wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixFirewall' could not be found. Checked paths: WixFirewall

C:\Users\root\Downloads\glpi\glpi>wix build  glpi_.wxs -ext WixFirewallExtension
wix.exe : error WIX0144: The extension 'WixFirewallExtension' could not be found. Checked paths: WixFirewallExtension
```

Answer (score 0):

In WiX v4 extensions are added via nuget.  You want to add this package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/WixToolset.Firewall.wixext

wix extension add -g WixToolset.Firewall.wixext

wix extension list -g

But to be honest, Wix has really nice Visual Studio/MSBuild Support.  You may find that path easier then direct commandline.